# Best way to find and replace old components using Angular + Nx

Tags: javascript, angular, abstract-syntax-tree

I have an Nx monorepo, with three Angular apps (all version 14), and a lib with some UI components.

I want to create an NX executor that finds and replaces old components with newer ones. For example:

```html
<!-- What I have -->
<my-button-component></button>

<!-- What I want -->
<button my-button></button>
```

I need a script for this because there are multiple components to be replaced and multiple instances of each component. So my team decided to create a script.

Now, how would I go about doing this? I created the executor, but how do I actually analyze the project, update the modules and etc...

I was thinking about `ngast`, but I couldn't get it to work :/ I don't think it supports Angular 14.

I'm not even sure if AST is the tool for the job. I need a light here, please. Is there a proper tool for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways you can achieve this is forking [@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template](https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint/tree/main/packages/eslint-plugin-template). It has processors that are using [@angular-eslint/template-parser](https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint/blob/main/packages/template-parser) to parse Angular Templates.

Your plugin can look some kind similar to:

```js
export default createESLintRule<[], MessageIds>({
  create(context) {
    const parserServices = getTemplateParserServices(context);
    const source = context.getSourceCode();
    
    return {
      [`Element$1[name=my-button-component]`](element: TmplAstElement) {
        context.report({
          node: node,
          message: "Use 'button' instead of 'my-button-component'",
          fix: function(fixer) {
            const elementText = source.getText(element);
            const newText = elementText.replace('my-button-component', 'button');
            
            return fixer.replaceText(element, newText);
          }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

You can also use [button-has-type](https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint/blob/v14.1.2/packages/eslint-plugin-template/docs/rules/button-has-type.md#angular-eslinttemplatebutton-has-type) ([source](https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint/blob/v14.1.2/packages/eslint-plugin-template/src/rules/button-has-type.ts)) as an example and read about [applying fixes](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/developer-guide/working-with-rules#applying-fixes) in ESLint docs.